# Forced line break after option name

Tags: magento

Default product options view place the option name on a line, forces a line break, and then displays options beneath.

Anyone know where/which changes need to be made to remove the line break so that the option choice displays next to the option name?

I'm using Magento 1.6.2 Community. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with just css, just put a float left on the label and inputbox.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out where a template file is located in magento is to turn on template path hints

See [How do I turn on template path hints](https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints)

Also you may want to use 'chrome inspect element' or 'firebug for firefox' to see if you can restyle it using css.